# VirtualBox installation message in Terminal: "this system is currently not set up to build kernel modules"

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, gnome-terminal, guest-additions, guest-os

Full Terminal message: 
[Image in a link to imgur i guess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oio4T.png)

(AskUbuntu doesn't let me quote the whole thing here for some reason even though i tried to format it as the rules say.. so don't crucify me over it)

should i install the "make gcc perl packages"? If i should, how? 
If there is a better way to fix the kernel issue, then please tell.

BTW: Im using ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and VirtualBox 6.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code should be as code - either use backticks or click {} - and has no limit. Code shouldn't be as quotes ;)

Comment: And you just need to install the dependencies mentioned in the error message.

Comment: You haven't installed the required dev tools like gcc etc!

Answer (score 2):

Please install the Ubuntu metapackage that contains the needed tools for compiling virtualbox modules:

```
sudo apt install build-essential linux-kernel-headers
```